# How to filter foreign key choices in admin form based on another field while changing (before saving)

Tags: django, django-admin

I have a model with two foreign key fields

```
class LabTesting(models.Model):
    fk_farm = models.ForeignKey("Farm", verbose_name=_("Farm"), on_delete=models.SET_NULL, null=True, blank=True)
    fk_house = models.ForeignKey("House", verbose_name=_("House"), on_delete=models.SET_NULL, null=True, blank=True)
```

fk_house has a fk_farm foreign key field I want to limit the fk_house choices in admin page to the selected farm but while changing before clicking save

I tried to edit the form but I couldn't get it to work dynamically in the change list page without saving the object

Comment: Welcome to StackOverFlow. Please take the [Tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour). Please read, [How to ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). Also please read [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: [django admin update select choice according to another select](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63207845/how-to-change-select-tag-options-according-to-another-select-tags-option-in-dja)

Comment: you can check this one [update select choices according to another select](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63207845/how-to-change-select-tag-options-according-to-another-select-tags-option-in-dja)

Comment: @MerdanChariyarov the first link solves my question thank you.

Comment: @HazemElmahy if you don't want to write some javascript code then you can use django-autocomplete-light pakage. For more detail, https://django-autocomplete-light.readthedocs.io/en/master/tutorial.html#filtering-results-based-on-the-value-of-other-fields-in-the-form